# INSERT INTO statement fails

Tags: php, sql

I've been receiving this problem for a week now and every theory of mine and fixes won't work. So I came here to ask for some help.

First off, whenever the customer clicks the purchase button after they select the item that they want to buy, this will then be executed:

```
    if(isset($_POST['shopBuyItem'])) {
                if( @odbc_exec($odbc_connect, $strUpdateBalance)
                    AND
                        @odbc_exec($odbc_connect, '
                            INSERT INTO [' . $_CONFIG['db_databases']['web'] . '].dbo.[LOG_PURCHASES] (
                                item,
                                itemname,
                                itemcount,
                                itemcurrency,
                                itemworth,
                                account,
                                datetime
                            ) VALUES (
                                ' . cleanSqlInput($mixedSelectedItemDetailsArray['itemid']) . ',
                                \'' . cleanSqlInput($mixedSelectedItemDetailsArray['name']) . '\',
                                ' . cleanSqlInput($mixedSelectedItemDetailsArray['count']) . ',
                                ' . $intGetCurrentCurrency . ',
                                ' . cleanSqlInput($mixedSelectedItemDetailsArray[$intWorthColumnHelper]) . ',
                                \'' . cleanSqlInput($_SESSION['user']) . '\',
                                \''. date($_CONFIG['web_date_format']['dbDatetime']) .'\'
                            )
                        ')
                    AND
                        send_item($intCharacterID, $mixedSelectedItemDetailsArray['itemid'], $mixedSelectedItemDetailsArray['count'])
                ) {
                    echo createMessage($_LANG['success_item_bought'], 'success');
                }
                else {
                    echo createMessage($_LANG['error_item_could_not_be_sent'], 'fail');
                }
            }
```

This is the send_item function:

```
function send_item($playerid, $itemid, $quantity) {
    global $odbc_connect, $_CONFIG;

    if(is_numeric($playerid) AND is_numeric($itemid) AND is_numeric($quantity)) {
        if( @odbc_exec($odbc_connect, '
            INSERT INTO [' . $_CONFIG['db_databases']['chr'] . '].dbo.[ITEM_SEND_TBL] (
                m_idPlayer,
                serverindex,
                Item_Name,
                Item_count,
                idSender
            ) VALUES (
                \''.$playerid.'\',
                \'01\',
                \''.$itemid.'\',
                \''.$quantity.'\',
                \'0000000\'
            )
        ')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will just go to return false and the values to be inserted in the database is not there, so I assume it is because of the INSERT INTO statement right? The thing is that, I am not touching any of the code regarding this before and this just happens. Though, it has connection to the sql server since items that are in the database can just be fetched without any problem. Just with the functions that has INSERT INTO has the problem. Do you guys have any ideas what could be wrong?

*Last week, I have used this ram cleaner where your memory will be drained.
[Reference](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=iobit%20ram%20cleaner)

Could this be the reason for the sql to behave differently?

Comment: Please add the error message. You may remove the `@` from `@odbc_exec` to see more errors.

Comment: The amazing thing on your `cleanSqlInput` function is that it shows that someone **knew** about sql injection, yet decided not to use parameterized queries and write his own escaping function.

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen hi, I did what you told me and then whenever I check the logs from the control panel of xampp "Logs -> PHP(php_error_log), it says that the system cannot find the path specified.".